# Rails server error when copying LIMMYSQL.dll from MySql to Ruby bin folder

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I copy LIMMYSQL.dll from MySql and put it in Ruby bin folder and then start rails server and I am getting below error. Please help me

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32
application.   - c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
        from d:/merlin_demo_app/demo_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this, eventually!

I re-installed Ruby and Rails under RVM. I'm using Ruby version 1.9.2-p136.

After re-installing under rvm, this error was still present.

In the end the magic command that solved it was: